# FTP server file being locked during upload

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, filezilla

An application regularly polls a directory for input csv files which arrive by FTP, so there is an FTP server (currently Filezilla Server) running on that computer.

The problem is, that if a file is in the middle of being uploaded when the application decides to poll the location, then the file is locked and all sorts of unsightly errors are thrown on the application, ruining the user experience.

Now assuming I can't modify the application to wait, is there anything that can be done about this? 
e.g. The server automatically moving or renaming the file once the upload is complete? Or wait for the upload to be complete before saving the file? Or are there other servers that offer solutions such as this?

Comment: "automatically moving or renaming the file once the upload is complete" – Normally you need the client to send proper commands and the server to understand them. FTP as a protocol [supports deleting, renaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands); see `DELE`, `RNFR`, `RNTO`. But this originates on the client side; you're seeking solution that works on the server. That's why my comment is not an answer. This smells like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). It's good you described a broader picture. Maybe you will consider this client-side approach.

Comment: I've seen this before with large files that are many gigs where something on the server touches or moves a partially uploaded file before the upload is complete. Errors such as "*Cannot Create Remote File*" and "*Copying Files to Remote Side Failed*". I know storage limits/quotas can cause these too but I have seen this occur when something on the server side messes with the partially uploaded file.

Comment: Consider uploading to the server across the slower WAN, etc. connection as `filename.tmp` or something different the process will not touch and then once fully uploaded, run a rename/mv command to rename the fully 100% uploaded file to the file name it needs to be. Furthermore, consider uploading to a /tmp subfolder and then once uploaded, move to the root upload directory or whatever. The upload across the slower WAN usually takes the longest so perhaps the local rename or move command will be much faster and prevent this issue.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I thought of doing this alright, but will the rename be instant, in the sense that the file will be unlocked as soon as the rename is complete? I ask because sometimes the upload takes several seconds between the file being created and being released, even if it's a very small file, like 30-40 bytes. Also I've edited the question, to make your comment more of an answer.

Comment: I don't know, I rarely use FTP. If I were you I would just test it.

Comment: @colmde It seems like you tagged the wrong person back about the comment I left you regarding the rename or move per the FTP. Yes, the rename or move will occur very quickly but if the rename will suffice, I'd go with that rather than the move of the file. Basically the logic or script you use to upload the files or whatever, just have the file be uploaded with the dummy name and then the very next command you use in your logic that does the FTP commands, run the rename command against the file that's uploaded for the app to see or whatever. Give it a whirl and see how it goes.I know FTP well.

Comment: If you can edit and show the logic you are using for the FTP upload portion, I can see if I can help show you the commands, etc. as I describe. Tag me back and I'll help if I have time but this should be a very simple task without recreating the wheel though.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the approach where your application does not poll the location that used by other process(FTP server in this case) to write. 
Instead, set the process to rnfr/rnto (atomic operation) files after they arrive to the locations that your app polls... Your should try to take readlock on the file and if failed skip it until next  attempt.
Another aproach is to use a marker file that will be arriving last in the batch of files and signals to you polling app that it can start processing csv files

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the same problem with below approach:

1. Connect to FTP
2. Gets list of files into an array (filter out .end files)
3. Rename each file in the array (add .end to the filename)
4. If got error while renaming skip that file (means that file is still uploading by other app)
5. Download each *.end file & delete (Or rename to .fin etc.)